# How to load parameters from two tensorflow models and output one model file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow-slim

Let's say I have two tensorflow models(A and B) with exactly the same graph but different weights in each layer. I want to merge layers conv1, conv2, conv3 from A and layers conv4, conv5, conv6 from B into one model C. Model C has the same structure as A and B, but different weights. I know how to separetly load layers from each model using the following code and made two seprate models each containing only conv1,2,3 or 4,5,6. But I don't know how to build a model C with conv1,2,3,4,5,6.

```
     exclude1=['conv1',...]
     exclude2=['conv4',...]
     variables_to_restore1=slim.get_variables_to_restore(exclude=exclude1)
     variables_to_restore2=slim.get_variables_to_restore(exclude=exclude2)
     saver1 = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore1)
     saver2 = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore2)
     saver1.restore(sess,args.model)
     saver2.restore(sess,args.model)
     saver1.save(sess, "Model/convlayers1.ckpt")
     saver2.save(sess, "Model/convlayers2.ckpt")
```

I've been learning tensorflow for a few months but has not seen something like this. Thank you very much!